# Question: Disappearing bees

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality, post-notice

The answers on the question [Are bees disappearing and why?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/286/82), while giving a nice editorial, are most likely obsoleted by current research.

There are two problems here:

- The answers predate most of the discussions on on answers quality and are thus not up to standards. The accepted answer links to Wikipedia and gives a vague explanation only.
- It is my understanding that [current research by Jeff Pettis](http://www.moraybeedinosaurs.co.uk/neonicotinoid/Pettisetal2012Naturwissen.pdf) (and other groups) all but solved the problem. Independent verification is still outstanding, however. Even so, this seems to be the most likely explanation yet. Unfortunately, the question currently doesn’t echo that and is very misleading to readers.

I would suggest putting a “current research” or similar banner on the question to warn casual readers that this is a hot topic of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I didn't find the argument very convincing, I gave you the benefit of the doubt (given the stakes are pretty low). I added the "current event" post notice. I also added some comments and downvoted some of the competing answers that don't follow our standards.

I don't understand though why this question is particularly special. The theory behind Stack Overflow is your better answer should stand on its merits and eventually catch-up and overtake the accepted answer. (Help it along with a comment on the wrong answer, pointing out its flaws.)

Why shouldn't that approach work here?

Comment: The problem is that the question is old, has an (unacceptable) accepted answer and may not receive the necessary attention from the OP. It’s special only because I noticed it now. My first thought was to simply flag it – I should have done that instead.

Comment: Furthermore, I didn’t want to write an own answer at first because I was unable to find the original reference(s). That’s now obsolete.